# How to make an array of structs?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I would like to know if I can make an array of structs, then use it in a foreach loop.

```
struct A { int a; }; 
struct B { int b; }; 
struct C { float c; };
```

And then:

```
int main()
{ 
     A a; B b; C c; 

     //Here I want to make an array of a, b and c,
     //then use it in for loop with the ints and floats. 

}`
```

Comment: Long answer: Yes you can

Comment: @40two: Not sure OP really means array... (but I think OP want something like `std::tuple`).

Comment: You can make arrays of any type of objects, not just `struct`s.

Comment: Show how you would use the foreach loop.

Comment: @40two but he used different structs can this be done ?

Comment: I think you're asking if you can put `a`, `b`, and `c` in the same array and iterate over the different-typed objects. This isn't trivially possible or idiomatic in C++, but there is probably an alternate way to solve your real problem.

Comment: hm I guess you can't make an array with three structs with different type...

Comment: @mohaned Where does the OP use different `struct`s?

Comment: @40two `Here i want to make an arr of a, b and c,` he said array not arrays (I think he means one array of all structs).

Comment: I got the same reading as @Mark B, the OP is asking for a container of objects of unrelated types

Comment: What will the loop do with the objects?

Comment: Building an array of unrelated types is usually a terrible idea and the C++ compiler is designed to protect you from making that kind of mistake. It is called the **type** system. However it is sometimes useful to store collections different types that are related to one another. This kind of polymorphism is well supported in C++ but how you go about it really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't safely make an array of unrelated types in C++.

If you have the need to put objects together in a container, then they are probably somewhat related : you should think about adding a common base class to `A`, `B` and `C`, and then manipulate an array (or `vector`...) of (smart) base class pointers.

However, think about the possible alternative of defining a type encapsulating your struct, instead of declaring this "array" :

```
struct T {
   A obj1;
   B obj2;
   C obj3;
};
```

**Note :**

- If you *really* need type erasure, then `boost::any` or `boost::variant` are very handy to encapsulate objects or any type.

Comment: It's an good alternative, but my structs have some parameters, how can i call a struct within a struct with arguments?

Comment: @Lerio : if you need to pass argument when you first initialize it, consider adding a constructor. Else, simply access a member with `t.obj1.my_member`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, but you cannot make an array of unrelated types/structs without using external libraries:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Person
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
    std::string job;
};

int main()
{
    Person people[10];

    //I am a normal one.
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        people[i].name = "usar";
        people[i].age = i;
        people[i].job = "Astronaut";
    }

    //foreach loop
    for(Person p: people)
    {
        std::cout << "Name: "<< p.name << "\n";
        std::cout << "Age: "<< p.age << "\n";
        std::cout << "Job: "<< p.job << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: he asks about creating array of different structs (different elements type in the same array)

Comment: My answer has been updated!

Comment: "but you cannot make an array of unrelated types/structs" technically you can do that through `boost::variant` or simple union, bigger question is should you?

Comment: @Slava, agree, see my answer.

Comment: @quantdev Thank you for making me notice it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Just create it just as other types. Assume that we have a struct of Car

```
struct Car
    {
           int engine;
           string brandName;
    };
```

You can create it like

```
Car list[2]={{3000, "BMW"},{2200, "Mercedes-Benz"}};
```

or just

```
Car list[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have "array" of different types, it is technically possible in C++ though not simple. At least not for novice C++ programmers. First of all you would need to use non trivial data type like `boost::variant` or `std::tuple`, second - accessing that data will require template metaprogramming, which is also not easy for beginners. But most probably your problem has simpler solution and can be solved more easily, you are just looking into wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Base
{

    virtual ~Base(){}

    virtual int GetInt()
    {
        throw "Not implemented";
        return 0;
    }
    virtual float GetFloat()
    {
        throw "Not implemented";
        return 0.0f;
    };
};

struct A : public Base
{
    int a;
    virtual int GetInt()
    {
        return a;
    }
};

struct B : public Base
{
    int b;
    virtual int GetInt()
    {
        return b;
    }
};

struct C : public Base
{
    float c;
    virtual float GetFloat()
    {
        return c;
    }
};

int main()
{ 
    A a; B b; C c; 

    Base* array[ 3 ] = { &a, &b, &c };
}
```

Comment: No need for the "return" in the Base class.

Comment: While this works, it's not really a regular C++ solution. The structures all seem unrelated and this violates LSP.